# How to pass date parameter from cell to power query Kusto source

Tags: excel, dynamic, parameters, powerquery, azure-data-explorer

I would like to pass 2 date parameters from cells in my excel workbook with the following Kusto query in power query of excel.

= AzureDataExplorer.Contents("https://test.net/", "myDB", "table#(lf)| where ChangedOn >= datetime(2023-02-01 00:00:00) and ChangedOn <= datetime(2023-02-28 23:59:59)", [])

= AzureDataExplorer.Contents("https://test.net/", "myDB", "table#(lf)| where ChangedOn >= datetime(" & "2023-02-01 00:00:00" & ") and ChangedOn <= datetime(" & "2023-02-01 00:00:00" & ")", [])

= AzureDataExplorer.Contents("https://test.net/", "myDB", "table#(lf)| where ChangedOn >= datetime(" & myParameter1 & ") and ChangedOn <= datetime(" & myParameter2  & ")", [])

myParameter1 = a start date value from a cell in excel
myParameter2 = an end date value from a cell in excel

The first 2 examples work in fetching the data but I am not able to figure out how to create and pass a custom date parameter that comes from a cell in excel. I would like ability to change start and end dates in excel and fetch those records after clicking refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Define a range name in excel, and populate it

[image]

Read that value into powerquery

```
Date1= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="date"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
```

replace hard coded date with reference to that variable, properly formatting it with DateTime.ToText using documentation at

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/datetime-totext

example

```
Date1= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="date"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = "where ChangedOn >= datetime(2023-02-01 00:00:00)",
Source2 = "where ChangedOn >= datetime("&DateTime.ToText(Date1, [Format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"])&")"
```